# I get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

Tags: python, file, valueerror

I have a part inside my code where I receive data from a text file, this is that part:
    last_score_file = open("/Users/lvanrem/PythonTest/last_score2", "r")

```
last_score_temprature = int(last_score_file.readline(1))
last_score_guess = int(last_score_file.readline(2))
add_to_random = int(last_score_file.readline(3))
last_score_file.close
```

it requests date from this file:

```
0
0
0
```

and it gives this error

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

let me know if you can help me...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The line you read has `\n` in it so the value is incorrect.
The 'readline(x)' read the next x characters so your out put will be like '0, \n, 0\n'
Try:

```
with open("/Users/lvanrem/PythonTest/last_score2", "r") as f:
   last_score_temprature = int(f.readline())
   last_score_guess = int(f.readline())
   add_to_random = int(f.readline())
```

Answer (score -1):

trim endline from read value

```
last_score_temprature = int(last_score_file.readline(1).strip())
last_score_guess = int(last_score_file.readline(2).strip())
add_to_random = int(last_score_file.readline(3).strip())
last_score_file.close
```

Comment: please dont copy answers in SO

Comment: well it solved that error, but I added this one: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''